# Want to open Notification Manager when a service is performed in background

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I am scheduling a task at specific time, so whenever in background that app service is performed i want to receive server response message on notification Manager.

```
     JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(HttpURLout, "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
```

Log cat Message.

E/Create Response: {"success":1,"message":"Office IN Marked THANKU!"}

I want this message on Notification Manager to keep updated that service is performed.

Answer (score 0):

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id";
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.notification_color))
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText(json.optString("message"))//your response string here

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,"Channel name",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT));
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: what is channel_ID here

Comment: Its required for target android version above 26 . Check these links
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.androidauthority.com/android-8-0-oreo-app-implementing-notification-channels-801097/amp/

Answer (score 0):

```
String CHANEL_ID = "Chanel_Id";
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Demo")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
            .setContentText(json.optString("message"))
            .setOngoing(true);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, STATUS_ICON_REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notif = builder.build();
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    mNotificationManager.notify(STATUS_ICON_REQUEST_CODE, notif);
```